# Why pymysql conn.close() is performed CORS error?

Tags: aws-lambda, pymysql

First, I ask for your understanding of my poor English.

AWS API Gateway(HTTP API, CORS setup has not done anything.) + Lambda + Pymysql is currently in use.
The odd thing about this is that 'conn.close()' before 'return data' results in a CORS error.

Below is the code and actual error screen.

```
def lambda_handler(event, context):
    sg_dict = {}
    try:
        cur = conn.cursor()
        sg_dict = sg_select_query(cur)
        if sg_dict != {}:
            sg_dict = ec2_select_query(cur, sg_dict)
        
        conn.close()
        return {
            'statusCode': 200,
            'headers': {
                'Access-Control-Allow-Headers': 'Content-Type',
                'Access-Control-Allow-Origin':  '*',
                'Access-Control-Allow-Methods': 'GET'
            },
            'body': json.dumps(sg_dict)
        }
    except:
        import traceback
        print(traceback.format_exc())
        conn.close()
        return {
            'statusCode': 500,
            'body': 'error'
        }
```

[CORS error with 'conn.close()'](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HylP0.png)

However, changing 'conn.close()' to '#conn.close()' will perform normally.

[Normal with '#conn.close()'](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O5F0Y.png)

I really don't know why this is happend. Please, share you experience.
thank you.

--- added image on 210414 11:17 (GMT + 9) ---

[call once conn.close()](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qrQRU.png)

[raise exception(call conn.close()](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ku2zk.png)

[normal execution(do not call conn.close()](https://i.stack.imgur.com/32JLs.png)

Comment: I can see there are 2 conn.close, one in each try and catch block. Which one is causing issue? Can you share some logs as well?

Comment: every time the lambda returns a 500 it will result in CORS error in the browser (that's normal).  Please add the log result of print(traceback.format_exc())

Comment: Changed to run conn.close() only once in lambda code.(please check added image on  my question.) Nevertheless, CORS errors continue to occur. ;-(. I'll look for the log.

Comment: has pymysql connection auto close function? No error performed at don't call 'close' function.